# I can not use Afx global functions in MFC

Tags: mfc, visual-c++, afx

I am improving an application writen in VC++.
I want to add a function that would send and receive messages. I used a callback function. In callback function, I used `::AfxGetMainWnd` to get the main window's handle.
When I input ::Afx, there is not related Afx appare to let me choose. And `AfxGetMainWnd` function does not work in program.

Please help.

Comment: What's the error when you do try and use it?

Comment: You mean to say Auto-complete in Visual Studio doesn't appear? That's not the problem, you can still use `AfxGetMainWnd` !

Comment: Do other parts of the program use MFC or are you trying to introduce it into a program that never used it?